# How can I print a single space character without a new line?

Tags: batch-file

I want to print only a space character ( ), without new line using batch file.

```bat
rem try to echo single space character with `echo|set /P= `
echo|set /P=
```

However, this does not print any character.

Comment: It would help if you were to put your question into context, so that responders can provide the most suitable method for your specific task.

Comment: The `SET/P` command consumes all leading spaces. The trick to doing this is to capture the backspace key into a variable. Then your set command can look like this. `SET/P ".=X%BS% "<NUL` Search the forums for the code to capture a backspace. It has been discussed several times.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your concrete problem. 
Do you only need to show a single space on the screen or do you need to put it into a file?

Showing it only can be solved with set/p show any character followed by a backspace and a space.

To put a single space into a file it's a bit more complex.

```
@echo
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
call :createSub
call :echoWithoutLinefeed "=hello"
call :echoWithoutLinefeed " world"
exit /b

:echoWithoutLinefeed
> txt.tmp (echo(%~1!sub!)
copy txt.tmp /a txt2.tmp /b > nul
type txt2.tmp
del txt.tmp txt2.tmp
exit /b

:createSub
copy nul sub.tmp /a > nul
for /F %%a in (sub.tmp) DO (
   set "sub=%%a"
)
del sub.tmp
exit /b
```

[Output text without linefeed, even with leading space or equal sign](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4213)

Comment: I just was about to comment that `copy` is not necessary since `type` stops at the (first) EOF/SUB character anyway, but I found out I would have been wrong; `type` seems to stop only when outputting to the console directly (even `>&2`), but not when redirecting to a file or piping (hence `type txt.tmp` displays not the same as `type txt.tmp | more`);...

Comment: ...interestingly, when outputting to the console, `type` seems to stop *reading*, not outputting (to prove that, I created a huge file that took several seconds to be read by `type txt.tmp > nul`, but when inserting SUB/EOF after the first few characters, `type txt.tmp > nul` still lasted some time, but `type txt.tmp` finished instantly)...

Answer (score 2):

You may create one or several text files that just contain spaces with no LineFeed at end, and then use it/they in any way you wish. For example, before `set /P` or `echo` commands, to show it in the screen or in a file, etc...

```
@echo off
setlocal

call :CreateSpaces 3 5
type Spaces3.txt
set /P "=After 3 spaces" < NUL
type Spaces5.txt
set /P "=After 5 spaces" < NUL
echo   After 2 spaces
goto :EOF


:CreateSpaces
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
:loop
if "%~1" equ "" del Spaces.tmp & exit /B
set "Spaces="
for /L %%i in (1,1,%~1) do set "Spaces= !Spaces!"
for %%X in (^"^
% Do NOT remove this line %
^") do set /P "=X%%~X%Spaces%" < NUL > Spaces.tmp
findstr /V "X" Spaces.tmp > Spaces%1.txt
shift
goto loop
```

Comment: Nice solution with `findstr`. I tried it without temporary file, but failed as a pipe seems to add always a cr/lf at the end